# Как передать список параметров в функцию в R

Tags: r

Как сделать подобное правильно?

```
params = list(mean = 0,sd = 1)
rnorm(n = 10,params);
```

Answer (score 4):

Например, с помощью функции `do.call`:

```
R> params = list(n = 5, mean = 0, sd = 1)
R> do.call(rnorm, params)
[1] -0.01897542 -0.96156942  0.26257890  0.63149632  2.92846340
```